# Linq filter array which contains multiple types which are inherited from a base type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a base class named `A` and two subclasses `B` and `C`:

```
class B : A
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class C : A
{
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting an array from a method which returns array of `B` and `C`, and 
I want to ignore the items in the collection if the `B.Description == "some text";`

Please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: show relevant code in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<A> list = ....
var query = list.OfType<B>().Where(b => b.Description != "some text");
```

If you also want all which is not `B`:

```
var query = list.Where(a => !(a is B) || ((B)a).Description != "some text"));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How to get both A and B but ignore B if the description == "some text";

Comment: @MukilDeepthi: have a look.

Comment: @CoderofCode: it doesn't work better since `String` overloads the `==` operator to compare the values not only the references. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx But `Equals` allows to compare case-insensitive which is not possible with `==`.